# Client and Server Input and Output

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, client-server

I have a client that reads the user input then sends it to the server. Then the server is suppose to send the input back and the client is suppose to read it.

```
while(true)
        {
            String input = "";
            while (input != null){
            input = "";
            try {
                input = in.readLine();

            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println(e1 + "Exception occured when reading user input");
            }
            // Sleep
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(USER_THROTTLE);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(toString()+" has input interrupted.");
            }

            if (input != null && allowedInputs.contains(input)){action_event(input , out, socket);}
        }
        }
```

This is the server side trying to get input from the user.

Here is the action_event method.

```
public static void action_event(String input, PrintWriter out, Socket socket)
{
    System.out.println(input);
    if(input .equals("w")){out.println("Got input from you : " + socket.toString() );}
}
```

The code below is the clients which runs in a while loop from reading to writing back and forth.

Here is the while loop.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    User_Connection user = new User_Connection();
    user.set_up();

    while (true){

    user.write();
    user.read();

    }

}
```

Below this are the write and read methods.

```
    public void write()
{
    String input = "";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    input = scan.nextLine();
    out.println(input);
}

public void read()
{
    String server = "";
    while (server != null){
    server = "";
    try {
        server = in.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(server != null){System.out.println(server);}
    }
}
```

When I enter "w" on the client, the server gets it and replies back. Then when I enter "w" again on the client, the server does not get it and does not reply back. I do not understand why this is happening. I would appreciate any help. If I need to post anymore information I would be happy to upon request.

Comment: Where is the loop for writing from client?

Comment: did you provide suffiecient information??

Comment: I just added the while loop.

Comment: You need to use two different threads for Reading and for Writing. Because your main thread have been just blocked on read operation.

Comment: On the Server side or the Client side. If on the server side how do I manage two threads per user. This is suppose to be a game server that handles user input.

Comment: If you want to have many clients, you need to look up Java NIO api. I recommend you to try NETTY lib for it. http://netty.io/ .This is very powerful network library. Also apache mina is good too. https://mina.apache.org/

Comment: I still do not know why I need multiple threads because once it finished reading shouldn't it go to the writing method back in main ??